# Spring @Cacheable annotation for same method in different service

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cache

I have implemented the standard redis caching template in a Spring boot application as per the following [article](http://caseyscarborough.com/blog/2014/12/18/caching-data-in-spring-using-redis/):

What I have is two different services that get a list of objects:

```
@RequestMapping("/admin/test/list")
public String testCache() {

    List<Cocktail> cocktails = cocktailsService.list();
    List<Ingredient> ingredients = ingredientsService.list();

    return "index";
}
```

Note: that the method name and signature is the same (i.e. `list()` ) but they both have different cache names as such:

```
// CocktailService
@Cacheable(value = “COCKTAILS”)
public List<Cocktail> list() {
    return repository.findAll();
}

// IngredientsService
@Cacheable(value = “INGREDIENTS”)
public List<Ingredient> list() {
    return repository.findAll();
}
```

**The Problem**

Even thou the cache name is different the method is always returning the list from the cache as there is no distinction at method level when generating the keys.

**Possible Solutions**

I know three solutions could be:

1. Change the method name
2. Write a custom KeyGenerator
3. Set Cache SpEL to make use of #root.target such as:

   @Cacheable(value=”COCKTAILS”, key="{#root.targetClass}")
   @Cacheable(value=”INGREDIENTS”, key="{#root.targetClass}")

**Question**

But surly there must be a better way or not?

Comment: The cached data, in your services, will belong to different cache regions as specified with `@Cacheable` annotation i.e. they will belong to `COCKTAILS` and `INGREDIENTS` regions, therefore even if their keys are same, they will be cached in different cache regions. It seems that you're not getting the results as expected due to some other reason. Try to enabled logging of Spring Cache to see what is happening: **org.springframework.cache** with **TRACE** level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue in the article you've followed. When creating your **CacheManager** bean, you need to invoke `cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);`, only then the cache names *COCKTAILS* and *INGREDIENTS* will be used as Redis cache key discriminator.

Here is how you should declare your cache manager bean:

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);

    // Number of seconds before expiration. Defaults to unlimited (0)
    cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(300);
    cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
    return cacheManager;
}
```

Comment: Apparently when dealing with other caching solutions, Spring’s CacheManger usually contains a map of Cache (each implementing map like functionality) implementations that are backed by separate caches. Using the default RedisCacheManager configuration, this is not the case. Based on the javadoc comment on the RedisCacheManager, its not clear if this is a bug or simply incomplete documentation.

“…By default saves the keys by appending a prefix (which acts as a namespace).” https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/caching-with-spring-data-redis.html