# Spring part of the Service will not be dynamic proxy, leading to the use of @Cacheable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, cglib

I am using the version of SpringBooot 1.8. Using @Cacheable annotations in the Service layer does not cache the data. Through debugging, it is found that some of the Service objects in the Controller layer are proxied by cglib, but some of them are not. The wordings are similar in nature. Why does this happen and how should it be solved ?

ApplicationBoot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class WebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MovieServiceImpl extends ServiceImpl<MovieMapper,Movie> implements MovieService {
    @Resource
    private PlayService playService;
    @Resource
    private DownloadService downloadService;
    @Resource
    private PlayApiService playApiService;
    @Resource
    private AreaService areaService;
    @Resource
    private CategoryService categoryService;
    @Resource
    private IncrementRecordsService inService;

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "nowIsAndFuck")
    public Movie nowIsAndFuck() {
        log.debug("movie-test 执行查询:"+1);
        return this.selectById(1);
    }
}
```

Cache Config:

```
package com.aikanyingshi.web.core.config.cache;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurerSupport;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.KeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory;
import     org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import     org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.Resource;


@Configuration
@Component
public class RedisConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Resource
    private RedisConfigProperties redisConfigProperties;

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(){
        JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHostName(redisConfigProperties.getHost());
        factory.setPort(redisConfigProperties.getPort());
        if(redisConfigProperties.getPassword()!=null){
            factory.setPassword(redisConfigProperties.getPassword());
        }
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String,String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory){
        RedisTemplate<String,String> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        setSerializer(template);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
        cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(10);
        return cacheManager;
    }

    private void setSerializer(RedisTemplate<String, String> template) {
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer serializer
                = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class);
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        om.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
        serializer.setObjectMapper(om);
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(serializer);
    }

    @Override
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return (o, method, objects) -> {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(o.getClass().getName());
            sb.append(":");
            sb.append(method);
            for (Object object : objects) {
                sb.append(":");
                sb.append(object.toString());
            }
            return sb.toString();
        };
    }


}
```

Comment: I am not java guys, but does this help: [Spring @Cacheable annotation for same method in different service
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993681/spring-cacheable-annotation-for-same-method-in-different-service?rq=1)

Comment: Reply to the upstairs: the nature of the two issues is not the same